# VS 2022 won't install Dynamics SDK

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, microsoft-dynamics

I'm pulling in a project done by another developer who is unavailable.  The .net refrences are ok but the crm.sdk packages won't load.  I tried the right-click nuget manage which doen't work.  Then I tried the instructions found here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore#restore-using-visual-studio

It still can't find them.  I have reinstalled them using.
[image: VS image]

PM> dotnet restore
Determining projects to restore...
C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.sln]
C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package microsoft.identity.client. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.sln]
C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.OData.Core. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.sln]
C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.Odata.Edm. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.sln]
C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.2015. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.sln]
C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.csproj : error NU1102: Unable to find package NewtonSoft.Json with version (>= 13.0.2) [C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.sln]
C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.csproj : error NU1102:   - Found 1 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [ Nearest version: 9.0.1 ] [C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.sln]
C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package OdataHttpClient. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.sln]
C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package simple.odata.client. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.sln]
C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Spectre.Console. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.sln]
C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.sln]
C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.csproj : error NU1102: Unable to find package System.Net.Http with version (>= 4.3.4) [C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.sln]
C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.csproj : error NU1102:   - Found 3 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [ Nearest version: 4.3.0 ] [C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.sln]
C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package System.ServiceModel.Primitives. No packages exist with this id in source(s): Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.sln]
Failed to restore C:\CRM.Migrator\CRMMigrate\Migrator.csproj (in 172 ms).
PM>

Comment: The error message says that it only checked the VS Offline Packages feed, but it doesn't list nuget.org or any other feed. nuget.org is added by default to new nuget.config configurations, which means you accidentally, or some other tool, has removed it. You can either add it back, or delete/rename your `c:\users\username\AppData\Remote\NuGet\NuGet.Config`, and allow NuGet to regenerate the default config with nuget.org as a package source.

Comment: Hi GoBeavs, any update of this issue, does my answer be able to solve your issue? :)

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce your situation on my side:

[image]

This issue comes from there really doesn't have required packages in the source and also can't find them in cache.

Any way, those packages should exists in nuget gallery, so you solve the issue via add the nuget gallery to the package source:

[image]

---

Also, you have another way to achieve your requirements, go to path:

C:\Users<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\NuGet

there will be a file named Nuget.config, delete it, close the VS and reopen it.

After the above steps, the issue should also be able to solve.